# Loop always finishes, even with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am running some JavaScript code to test/understand the behaviour of setTimeOut.

I use this code:

```
var timerx1 ;

if (timerx1) window.clearTimeout(timerx1);
timerx1 = setTimeout(testme, 10);
```

To call this function:

```
function testme() {
    for (var c = 0; c < 900000; c++) {
        document.getElementById("divMode").innerHTML = c;
    } 
}
```

This loop will always finish before exiting.

I had expected that the setTimeOut of 10ms would 'kick' in and the loop aborted before completion.

I stress this is not part of any other code or application. I am just trying to understand how setTiemOut works and any limitations.

Comment: Your setTimeout function calls function called "LiveFeed", not "testme"

Comment: *Nothing* will interrupt your loop, aside from an error being thrown, or the browser quitting.

Comment: @cookiemonster Hi, thanks for confirming what appears to be the behaviour. So, what would be the point of using setTimeOut if it does not actually timeout?

Comment: You're completely misunderstanding `setTimeout`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout

Comment: slalks - thanks for that link. Looking at it now.  I must have been thrown by the name 'setTimeOut'.  So, does the interval dictate WHEN the function is called?

Comment: It *does* work as *I* expect. It doesn't work as *you* are expecting :)

Comment: :).  I stand corrected by all.  Feel a bit stupid now!

Comment: I now agree that this question should be closed.  But people have been kind to answer.  I will accept the answers below and let my peers decided to close or not. Thanks to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript runs tasks on a stack. Your for loop executes completely as one of those loops. When you use a `setTimeout` it takes the function you passed in and appends it to the end of that task stack. Then it will execute that task when appropriate.

```
                              // current thread  | waiting
doSomething();                //   execute now   |    --
setTimeout(doSomething, 10);  // append to stack | doSomething (8ms left)
doSomethingElse();            //   execute now   | doSomething (5ms left)
// End of current thread      //      --         | doSomething (0ms left) do this next
                              //    doSomething  |    --
```

SetTimeout returns immediately as if it was finished. It basically assigns the function to a pending state and will be executed *after* the current thread is finished (current function is over/returned) *and* the timeout timer is finished.

Comment: Just thought I would ask even though this is off from the original question but would executing on a different thread make the code 'quicker'?

Comment: @AndrewSimpson it depends on the code. If your talking about something that takes time to execute then in theory yes. But there is a slight performance hit to using setTimeout. Just remember that JavaScript is NOT multi-threaded. It only defers execution. It still executes in one thread serially. The order is what gets deferred.

Comment: Hi. again good clear answer. So if I want to execute code continuously but cannot guarantee how long it will take then the setinterval would not work either.

Comment: @AndrewSimpson You don not want setInterval it will keep pushing to the stack regardless. setTimeout will allow you to batch them instead. Take a look at [Underscore's implementation of throttle()](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) for an example on managing variable execution times.

Answer (score 2):

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) doesn't interrupt or "timeout" your loop: it merely **calls** the callback function after so much time has passed.

> Calls a function or executes a code snippet after a specified delay.

Answer (score 2):

setTimeout wait for the specified millisecond and the execute the function..  In your example you are waiting 10ms